# Ncurses library and reading from a file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, ncurses

What function should I use in order to read from a text file a line and then print it in a ncurses window. I’ve tried:

```
int main ( int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *src;
    src = fopen (argv[1], "r");
    WINDOW *my_win;
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    my_win=newwin(30, 30, 0, 0);

    char *s;
    s = malloc (500 * sizeof (char) ); 
    fgets( s, 500, src);
    mvwprintw(my_win, 3, 5, s);
    wrefresh(my_win);
    fclose(src);
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 1):

This should work in general, but you are calling `endwin()` without delay, so you won't have a chance to see your window. Try this:

```
...
fclose(src);
sleep(5);
endwin();
return 0;
```

}

to see your window before you end it.

If you are observing a segfault, make sure that your file open succeeds and of course make sure that you pass the filename as argument on startup:

```
FILE *src;
if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Filename missing!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
src = fopen (argv[1], "r");
if (src == NULL) {
    perror("fopen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Furthermore, this does not make much sense:

```
char *s;
s = malloc (500 * sizeof (char)); 
fgets( s, 500, src);
```

`malloc()` is for dynamically sized allocations (or very big allocations). Better use this:

```
char s[500];
fgets(s, sizeof(s), src);
```

And don't use `* sizeof(char)` in any case, it looks ugly and is unneeded, since `sizeof(char)` is always guaranteed to be `1`.